# Como sanitizar mis archivos con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio web en Internet y en el día de hoy un hacker logro entrar a mi base de datos en donde creo usuarios con el roll admin, ingreso al sistema exitosamente.

Logre pasar algunas palabras con él, editando un usuario se la base de datos y escribiendo logro decirme que no tenia malas intenciones y me dijo que sanitizara mis subidas de archivos.

Pero he buscado mucho por Internet y no encuentro nada para sanitizar mis subidas de archivos con **PHP**

Por favor alguien me ayude para que esto no se vuelva a repetir

Lo que si he hecho es verificar el tipo de imágenes que recibido

```
// Asegurarnos que la imagen contenga un formato de img
    if($imgType == "image/jpg" || $imgType == "image/png" || $imgType == "image/jpeg" || $imgType == "image/git" || $imgType == "image/gif" || $imgType == "image/webp" || $imgType == ""){

        // Verificar el peso de la imagen
        if($img['size'] >= $maxSize) {
            array_push($errors, 'La imagen pesa mucho, por favor solo 2MB');
        }

        if(!is_dir('./img-profile')){
            mkdir('./img-profile', 0777);
        }

        // Movemos la img a la carpeta img-profile
        move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], './img-profile/'.$imgName);

    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Lo siento, no aceptamos esta extensión: $imgName");
    }
```

No se si esta sea la forma de sanitisar a la que el hacker se refería.
Si necesitan mas información por favor solo háganmelo saber y yo con gusto la suministro.

Comment: Quizá no baste con sanitizar subida de archivos y tengas que hacer una revisión de todo tu código. Por ejemplo, ¿no usas consultas preparadas con datos que son proporcionados por los usuarios? en ese caso hay riesgo de *Inyección SQL*, y el alcance puede ser enorme. ¿Usas algún CMS tipo Wordpress u otro? Si es así tendrás que verificar que no tengas plugins vulnerables, así como plantillas, temas, etc. Es decir, cuando hay un hackeo deberías revisar todo el entorno buscando cualquier vulnerabilidad posible, lo sitios no se hackean solamente mediante la subida de archivos...

Comment: considera lo que te han dicho, la mejor forma para solventar el problemas de seguridad es refactorizar y validar que todo el. codigo de tu proyecto no tiene problemas de seguridad, tu prefunga es muy amplia y puede estar basada en opiniones incluso no has aportado un codigo o demostrado que codigo es el que tiene problemas de seguridad por esemotivi cualquier respuesta puede estar mal planteada o puede resultar erronea, recomendare cerrar esta pregunta. hasta que tengas dudas mas concretas o un problema real de codigo.

Answer (score 0):

## Esto no és una respuesta.

És un comentario, pero para dar formato y con tal de que quepa me veo en la obligación de añadirlo así.

Te dejo una lista de puntos a revisar:

- Validación por el lado del cliente
- Validación por el lado del servidor
- Validación Mime Type
- Bloquear extensiones de archivos peligrosas
- Comprobar el header de las imágenes
- Extensiones dobles de archivos
- Proteger la carpeta de subidas con .htaccess
- Subir los archivos en un directorio fuera del "server"
- Genera un nombre de archivo aleatorio

Ejemplo de código para el `.htaccess`

```
deny from all

    <Files ~ “^w+.(gif|jpe?g|png)$”>

    order deny,allow

    allow from all

    </Files>
```

Como puedes ver el contenido sobre el que preguntas es demasiado extenso como para poder hacer una respuesta razonablemente corta. Puedes ir preguntando según tengas dudas sobre cada uno de esos puntos.

Seguramente me deje algún punto por señalar...